# OTP autofill with multiple textfields

Tags: ios, swift, verification, one-time-password

I have 6 independent text fields as ;
[image: tf]

I would like to read otp suggestion from the keyboard to fill them in. Is that possible?

[image: x]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you have multiple text fields or not, just be sure you're okay with the first responder which must be changed when the user enters.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you achieve it?